# Tracking GPS with node.js

Tags: node.js, gps

I try to track GPS device with node.js server. But server receives only IMEI in a form like this:

```
##,imei:359xxxxxxxxxxxx,A;
```

What i'm doing wrong? Here's code:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
  });
});

server.listen(2000);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You probably aren't doing anything wrong.  the device isn't sending you all the data.  Or, you need to respond to it to request the data.

Comment: Duncan_m, the problem is console should print all data (coordinates, time and etc). Brad, GPS sends all data, I tried GPS with other servers.

Comment: Data might be binary, and cant be just simply stringified. Or probably there is no data sent, as code looks absolutely fine.
Based on documentations of GPS device, you might need to do some request to receive data from it.

Comment: @Gugis can you provide the details of how to track some particular gps device with node js, if you have done this

Answer (score 0):

Is your GPS tracker a TK10* ?  It looks like it from the message your server got.  If so, you need to reply to the tracker with 'LOAD' to tell it it's logged on.  It will also send a heartbeat message periodically of just the IMEI to which the server must reply with 'ON'

Take a look at this document which has all of the commands/messages documented:
http://www.zhyichina.com/en/GPStracking/GPRS-Data-Protocol.xls